# How to deserialize an .XML into a list

Tags: .net, deserialization, xml-deserialization

Lets say I have an XML file with information of patients that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPatient xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Patient>
    <firstName>Vince</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    <dateOfBirth>05/05/1912</dateOfBirth>
    <phone>3056988877</phone>
    <email>random@google.com</email>
    <insurance>Humana</insurance>
    <typeOfPlan>PPA</typeOfPlan>
    <subID>123456</subID>
    <planID>654321</planID>
  </Patient>
  <Patient>
    <firstName>Mark</firstName>
    <lastName>Jones</lastName>
    <dateOfBirth>05/05/1992</dateOfBirth>
    <phone>3058877457</phone>
    <email>random@hotmail.com</email>
    <insurance>PlanB</insurance>
    <typeOfPlan>PPO</typeOfPlan>
    <subID>987987</subID>
    <planID>987987</planID>
  </Patient>
```

How can I load that information into a list of patients in Visual Studios? This is my attempt but I am getting an error:

```
Dim Patients As New List(Of Patient)
Dim p As New Patient
Dim reader As New StreamReader("..\..\patients.xml")
Dim serial As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of Patient)))
For Each paciente In serial.Deserialize(reader)
    Patients.Add(paciente)
Next
```

However it is throwing me an non handled expression error.

The patient class just has all the properties for all the fields in the XML.

Comment: What is the message of the exception?

Comment: And: in addition to the full message text: is this a compiler error? Or a runtime error? If it is runtime: make sure you also include the inner-exception's message - and all the way down until inner-exception is null.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* just be a casting thing. My VB is rusty, but in C#:

```
List<Patient> patients = (List<Patient>)serial.Deserialize(reader);
```

The serializer should already be returning a list.